# Callsign includes the term 'with Kilo' ; What does that signify?

Tags: general-aviation, radio-communications, call-sign

In FS-X I sometimes see **with Kilo** at the end of a Call-sign. For example the one from last night had

> **M**ike **S**ierra **A**lpha **B**ravo with **K**ilo

What does **With Kilo** mean?

Comment: Listen to the tower also, they will probably be saying something on the lines of "current information Kilo"

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7662/19), if not duplicate

Comment: It's just the ATIS version, so the tower and pilot can crosscheck they have the most recent weather/terminal information. They go up by one letter per version. So the next met release would be 'with Lima'. 'With information Kilo' is better than 'with Kilo'. Some airport terminal areas will also report the QNH for you, for your altimeter settings. This is on the ATIS/METAR report, but it can change quickly.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What that probably means is that the pilot is reporting that they have [ATIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_terminal_information_service) information kilo. Automatic Terminal Information Service (ATIS) is a radio broadcast on a specific frequency (often a local navaid like a VOR) which a pilot dials up to get weather and airport information before joining one of the airfield's frequencies. Each time the information is updated in a day the next letter of the alphabet is used; "information Kilo" means the information has been updated 11 times that day.

If the tower had to relay weather, runway in use and other instructions to everyone pilot who joined the frequency it would take loads of their time; ATIS is instead there so controllers can spend their time controlling. When a pilot introduces his/herself on frequency at an airfield they announce the latest ATIS they have so that the controller knows they have up to date information and they don't need it relayed.

From a phraseology standpoint just saying "with kilo" is okay. I usually say "with information kilo" because it makes sure that kilo isn't confused as being part of my callsign.

Comment: The first time I took my wife flying, in a two-seater, after we landed, she asked me, "Who is Charlie?"

Comment: Hahahaha @Flynn! She meant nothing to me honey, honest!

Comment: So... you can also expect “with Juliet” or “with Romeo?”

Comment: @RoboKaren Or perhaps "Yankee Papa Oscar with Whisky", oh dear...

Comment: Kilo? What are you saying, I've put on weight??

Comment: @GdD Nah, it's kilos, not pounds, so it's mass rather than weight. :)

Comment: @RoboKaren You could even hear "One Two Romeo with Juliet."

Comment: As Kennedy Steve regularly says, in response to "Delta 123 ready for taxi with Mike", "You and Mike can taxi for 23L via Alpha"

Comment: Now that's interesting!